# Trouble migrating from next.js to vite.js with custom app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, vite

I'm migrating from a react next.js app (with no `index.html` or `main.tsx`) written in javascript to a react vite.js app written in typescript (with `index.html` and `main.tsx`). I've been able to figure out almost everything except the following error, which occurs on my `src/main.tsx file`.

```
//src/main.tsx

import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import App from '../pages/_app' 
import './index.css'
import "../styles/globals.css";



ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App /> 
  </React.StrictMode>,
)
```

`<App />` throws the error:

```
Property 'pageProps' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'AppInitialProps<CustomPageProps>'.ts(2741)
```

And here is my App code written in the `_app.tsx` file, which is also where  `AppProps<CustomPageProps>` is defined:

```
//pages/_app.tsx
import Preloader from "../src/components/Preloader";
import "../styles/globals.css";
import { Fragment, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import React from 'react';
import type { AppProps} from 'next/app'
import '../src/App.css'

interface CustomPageProps {
  foo?: "bar"
}

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps<CustomPageProps>) {
  const [loader, setLoader] = useState(true);
  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setLoader(false);
    }, 1500);
  }, [])

  return (
    <Fragment>
      {loader && <Preloader />}
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </Fragment>
  );
}
```

For additional context, here is the `'pageProps'` code written in the `node_modules/next/.../utils.d.ts`

```
//node_modules/.../utils.d.ts

export type AppInitialProps<PageProps = any> = {
    pageProps: PageProps;
};
```

And, I wonder if the issue derives from the difference in file structure, in which I am still working out the kinks.

Old app file structure

[Old Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKiqh.png)

New app file structure

[Newer Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHO44.png)

Thank you for any help. I've looked at every resource I could find at github, stackoverflow, vite, react, next, typescript, and youtube. I've rewrittent the code several times.

I'm hoping to find a resolution to the error I keep getting in my main.tsx file. Thank you.